# How to assign clicked button text value to another selected Button Text Value in unity?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, button, text

I am displaying 4 questions and user will have to select answers from the given array of answer buttons at the bottom. to answer 1st question (22 + 6) user will have to select yellow button given next to it and then click any button from the bottom list. when any answer button is clicked , I want to assign that value to the provided yellow button . Then for next question(16 + 7) again user will have to select another yellow button and click answer button from the list. I am not able to assign value of clicked answer button to selected yellow button. Can anyone please suggest me how to achieve this please?

```
public class WithButtons : MonoBehaviour
{
     Text[] userInputs;
     public Text aValue = null, bValue = null, cValue = null, dValue = null;
     int a, b, c, d;
     public GameObject[] ansButtons;
     private GameObject tempGO;
     Text[] answers;

     private Button myButton;

     //-----------------------------------------------------------------------//
     void Start()
     {        
         PuzzleMaker();
     }

     public void PuzzleMaker()
     {

         a = Random.Range(0, 25);
         b = Random.Range(0, 25);
         c = Random.Range(0, 25);
         d = Random.Range(0, 25);

         aValue.text = a.ToString();
         bValue.text = b.ToString();
         cValue.text = c.ToString();
         dValue.text = d.ToString();


         ansButtons[0].GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = (a + b).ToString();
         ansButtons[1].GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = (c + d).ToString();
         ansButtons[2].GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = (a + c).ToString();
         ansButtons[3].GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = (b + d).ToString();
         ansButtons[4].GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = (a + a).ToString();
         ansButtons[5].GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = (b + b).ToString();
         ansButtons[6].GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = (c + c).ToString();
         ansButtons[7].GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = (d + d).ToString();           

     }

     //check which button is clicked
     public void WhichButtonIsClicked(string buttonName)
     {
         Debug.Log(buttonName);

         if (buttonName == "AB")
         {
             //assign value of clicked button to ? button Q1
             //userInput1.text = 
         }
         else if (buttonName == "CD")
         {
             //assign value of clicked button to ? button Q2

         }
         else if (buttonName == "AC")
         {
             //assign value of clicked button to ? button Q3

         }
         else if (buttonName == "BD")
         {
             //assign value of clicked button to ? button Q4

         }
     }    

    public void OnEnable()
     {
         myButton = GetComponent<Button>();
         myButton.onClick.AddListener(() => { ChangeTarget(); });
     }

    public void ChangeTarget()
    {        
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < ansButtons.Length; i++)
        {
            userInputs[i].text = 
            UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text.ToString();
        }      


    }

 }
```

Comment: @ Jannis i have assigned 4 answers and 4 random values. is their better method to do it? I am new to unity so not sure.

Comment: i have assigned 8 values first then i am shuffling those values so i dont get answer at the same location everytime

Comment: oh ok. then i will remove loop ans simply assign values and keep shuffle.wil that be fine?

Comment: removed it thanks . but can u possibly guide me to assign clicked  button text to selected button please

Answer (score 0):

you can assign text already as shown:

```
ansButtons[0].GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = (a + b).ToString();
```

You need to do basicly the same thing as up in this line of code
You need your ? button and the right ansButton

How to get these refernces?

The you get the first reference, when a yellow button is pressed.
you might have a code like this:

```
Button selectedYellowButton = null;

public void getMyYellowButton(string buttonNameEnding) {
Button yellowButton = GameObject.find("YellowButton" + buttonNameEnding);
selectedYellowButton = yellowButton;
}
```

Then when a ansButton is pressed, you simply assign

```
public void assignToYellowButton(string buttonNameEnding) {
if (selectedYellowButton != null) {
     Button ansButton = GameObject.find("AnsButton" + buttonNameEnding);
     selectedYellowButton.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = ansButtons[indexInArray].GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text;
     }
}
```

You can actually use any method to get the references you like.
Its up to you :)

Hope it helps :D

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining it very well. I am implementing it in my c# file. will update you soon.

Comment: In the inspector, I have assigned assignToYellowButton function to all 8 answer buttons and getMyYellowButton function to all 4 yellow buttons. But when i select any yellow button and click on any answer button, same value is assigned to yellow button. why do we have to pass int indexInArray value?

Comment: I mean I have passed on 0-7 int value to each answer button.but when I click on any of the answer button it is not passing on correct button text value to the selected yellow button.it is pulling value from the array and not what is shown on the button

Comment: Can we simply assign clicked button.text to selected yellow button.text??

Comment: @Sarita the indexInArray is just a reference. You can use again `Button ansButton = GameObject.find("AnsButton" + buttonNameEnding)`  and you can probably assign button.text to button.text its up to you to try out. sry for the not working solution

Comment: I used `UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>().text.ToString();`
 to assign clicked button value to selected and it worked. at least you explained me the process. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I have one solution. Yo can check it
[image]

public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

```
    public int _valueBtn1;
    public int _valueBtn2;
    public int _valueSelectedBtn;
    public bool wasClicked1 = false;
    public bool wasClicked2 =  false;


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    // BUTTON [?] - TOP
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        wasClicked1 = true;


    }

    // BUTTON [5]
    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (wasClicked1)
        {
            _valueSelectedBtn = Convert.ToInt32(this.button4.Text);
            button3.Text = _valueSelectedBtn.ToString();
            wasClicked1 = false;
        }
        else if (wasClicked2)
        {
            _valueSelectedBtn = Convert.ToInt32(this.button4.Text);
            button5.Text = _valueSelectedBtn.ToString();
            wasClicked2 = false;

        }
    }

    // BUTTON [?] - bottom 
    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        wasClicked2 = true;

    }

    // BUTTON [2]
    private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (wasClicked1)
        {
            _valueSelectedBtn = Convert.ToInt32(this.button8.Text);
            button3.Text = _valueSelectedBtn.ToString();
            wasClicked1 = false;
        }
        else if (wasClicked2)
        {
            _valueSelectedBtn = Convert.ToInt32(this.button8.Text);
            button5.Text = _valueSelectedBtn.ToString();
            wasClicked2 = false;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Button.text.

Simply, get the reference of the answer button on which you click.

```
string textAnswer ;
void OnAnswerButton1(text buttonName){
GameObject answerButton = GameObject.Find("buttonName");
 textAnswer = answerButton.text;

}
```

now you have text of that answer button in textAnswer variable.
So give this text to "?" button

you must be having some reference of "?" button.
So do it just like below

```
Button aBbutton; //reference of "?" button

aBbutton.text = textAnswer;
```